# Add-in is already requesting an access token in Microsoft outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an outlook addin to set signature. I'm trying to obtain the access token using the code below, I need to use the token to access Microsoft graph api to access logged in user content:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
   Office.actions.associate("onMessageComposeHandler", getToken());
};
function getToken(){
  try{
    let accessToken = Office.auth.getAccessToken().then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
  })
}catch(error){
   console.log(error)
}
}
```

I have been trying different ways as indicated in the documentation and other solutions either it displays an error that **another request has been made** and currently it is displaying this error, any ideas on how to solve this issue will be highly appreciated:
**OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'Error occurred in the authentication request from Office.', message: 'An unexpected error occurred in the client.', code: 13006}**

I have enabled the SSO as outlined [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). The addin is already configured in a microsoft test tenant. I'm still getting the same error, I have also tried to change the code as in the documentation:

```
async function getToken(){
  try{
    let accessToken = await 
      OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({allowSignInPrompt:true})
      console.log(accessToken)
  }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
  }
```

}

Comment: I have shared the credentials to the account

Comment: I have shared to the account

Comment: Could you confirm if the issue happens all the time or sometimes?

Comment: Since I began working on the tool, I have not been able to obtain the token even once

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SSO in the add-in, see [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) for more information. Be aware, you need to grant administrator consent to the add-in. This procedure is only needed when you're developing the add-in. When your production add-in is deployed to AppSource or the Microsoft 365 admin center, users will individually trust it or an admin will consent for the organization at installation.

Comment: I have enabled the addin as outlined and also in the exchange online tenant but it is still displaying the same error